# Why flask app run but browser is not loading the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I was developing a web application and it was woking fine, then I closed the project and re-opened it after a few hours, the project ran without error, but when I go to localhost:5000 it doesn't even load. I tried the same project in another laptop  and it works perfectly.
I also tried a simple project in the problematic one like this. The program run, but the browser won't load the page, also here if I use my second laptop it works perfectly. What I should do to fix? Literally like 2 hours ago was working fine

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  # put application's code here
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My application code is:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_login import current_user, LoginManager
from DaisPCTO.db import get_user_by_id
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "qwnfdopqwebnpqepfm"
    Bootstrap(app)
        
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = "auth_blueprint.login"
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @app.route("/")
    def home():    
        print("hello")             
        return render_template("page.html", user=current_user, roleProf = True if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.hasRole("Professor") else False)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(UserID):
        return get_user_by_id(UserID)

    from DaisPCTO.auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from DaisPCTO.courses import courses as courses_blueprint 
    app.register_blueprint(courses_blueprint, url_prefix="/courses")

    return app
```

i'm not putting all the blueprint, this is only the **init**.py file

Answer (score 3):

In you application you don't run your app you just create a function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

If you add this to your code you should be abble to see it in http://localhost:5000

Comment: The official flask documentation says you don't have to put if __name == "__main__" if your file name is __init__.py and you define a create app and returning it.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/factory/

However 2 hours ago the app was working fine, and if I use my second laptop it also works fine.

Comment: Yeah but defining and returning it won't run your app, also ``` __name__ == '__main__' ``` is up to you it is just good practice to add it so later you can use that code again.

Comment: Yes it does, read the docs

Comment: When you run init.py what does it output in the screen?

Comment: It says the app is running and I can go to localhost:5000.
I also said that in my second laptop the app works perfectly, and Im working on it for 2 weeks and it never gave me any problem

Comment: Serving Flask app 'DaisPCTO' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Add my code to your apllicatoon and try to enter the 127.0.0.1:5000 page

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: When you try to enter 127.0.0.1:5000 what does it show?

Comment: It show me nothing, literally nothing,infinite loading

Comment: Hmm i think to know the problem but I have one more question, how do you run your app when you add my code?

Comment: I just use flask run

Comment: Try running the file, you can use **python your_file_name.py** to run it trough command line

Comment: the flask enviroment won't be setted up if I run the app like this

Comment: Yeah but with the app.run it doesn't matter

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: I am sorry but I am out of suggestions, my idea of the problem is that you where creating the function but not initializing it,  and with flask run you runed the app var but the route was not defined. But if my code doesn't work for you and you get no error messages i don't know how to help, sorry ):

Comment: I tried running the code on my pc and it works for me

Comment: Do you have a folder with templates and a file named pages.html?

Comment: yeah I know it's working, I said on my second laptop it is working fine, it is the same folder as I share it via google drive. I don't think it is a code problem, if it was, it wouldn't work on my second laptop too. I bet it is like a browser cache problem or terminal problem or something else, I don't know

Comment: Oh sorry, if i can help on anything else please add a comment